# Using the interpolate function

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

What I need to do is read in a file with times, `x` and `y` positions.
The times go in terms of hours, however I want to produce the `x` and `y` positions at intervals of seconds instead.

I am so confused with this, as not sure if I treat it as 1D etc.
 Edit, the function relating time and positions is unknown, but there is a trend.

Comment: Your interpolation is 1d (only time), so use [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) use times as the first argument and x _and_ y combined into a single array as the second argument

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is define time in units and when you do the interpolation, make sure to just subdivide each interval into 3600. (Because there are 3600 seconds in an hour.

I created an example assuming an exponential and sinusoidal trend in x and y.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
mytime = np.arange(0, 10)
x = np.sin(mytime)
y = np.exp(-mytime/3.0)
f = interpolate.interp1d(mytime, x, kind = 'cubic')
g = interpolate.interp1d(mytime, y, kind = 'cubic')
mytimenew = np.arange(0, 9, 1/3600)
xnew = f(mytimenew)
ynew = g(mytimenew) 
plt.plot(mytime, x, 'o', mytimenew, xnew, '-')
plt.plot(mytime, y, 'o', mytimenew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The only problem is I don't know the trend of x and y,?